# Find difference between DateTimes in List

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a List of DateTimes

```
var times = CurrentMeter.SessionTimes.ToList();
```

How do I find the difference between them and add the results to a new List?

I want the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds between each datetime.

Comment: What do you mean by differences between them?  Do you want the differences between every combination of every pair in your list?  Or the difference against some specific time (eg, DateTime.Now)?

Comment: What's your problem? Finding the difference between datetimes or whatever operation your trying to do between items in a list. What have you tried?

Comment: Do you want to compare by Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds or even include Milliseconds?

Comment: Hours, seconds, milliseconds

Comment: For a list of 4 items do you want to generate list with 3 items (pairs:0-1, 1-2, 2-3) or the list with 6 items (pairs:0-1, 0-2, 0-3, 1-2, 1-3, 2-3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A difference between two `DateTime` objects is a `TimeSpan`.

This function will calculate the time delta between each consecutive pair of `DateTime`s.

It will iterate through each time in `times`, subtract the previous value from it, and add the difference to your result list.

```
IEnumerable<TimeSpan> CalculateDeltas(IEnumerable<DateTime> times) {
    var time_deltas = new List<TimeSpan>();

    DateTime prev = times.First();
    foreach (var t in times.Skip(1)) {
        time_deltas.Add(t - prev);
        prev = t;
    }

    return time_deltas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to calculate the difference between each item in the list. The results are stored in a `List<double>` and represent the total of seconds between each datetime.

```
var times = new List<DateTime>
{
    new DateTime(2014, 5, 28, 9, 57, 12),
    new DateTime(2014, 5, 28, 9, 57, 43),
    new DateTime(2014, 5, 28, 9, 58, 03),
    new DateTime(2014, 5, 28, 9, 59, 46),
    new DateTime(2014, 5, 28, 10, 0, 22),
};

var differences = new List<double>();

for(int i = 0; i < times.Count - 1; i++)
{
    differences.Add((times[i+1] - times[i]).TotalSeconds);
}
```

Output:

`31 
 20 
 103 
 36`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var time = new []{
    DateTime.Parse("14-4-2012 00:00:00"),
    DateTime.Parse("14-4-2012 01:12:34"),
    DateTime.Parse("14-4-2012 12:44:33"),
    DateTime.Parse("14-4-2012 23:12:42"),
};

var result = time.Zip(time.Skip(1), (a, b) => b - a)
                 .Select(d => new {d.Hours, d.Minutes, d.Seconds})
                 .ToList();
```

`result` is now:

[image]

(Note that this is a very simply approach and only works for differences < 24h. If you have greater differences, take into account `d.Days` etc.)